# slideMenuController not working

Tags: swift

i am using slideMenuController from github for left drawer effect.
i had implemented successfully.
but i am having one issue that from the menu i am navigate to viewController2 and viewController2 have one uibutton which push viewcontroller1. 
now i am selecting viewcontroller2 from slideMenuController but it navigate to viewcontroller1 instead of viewcontroller2.
i am having navigation in appdelegate

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    var mainViewController : MainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainViewController") as MainViewController
    let leftViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftViewController") as LeftViewController
    let rightViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RightViewController") as RightViewController

     nvc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)

    leftViewController.mainViewController = nvc

    let slideMenuController = SlideMenuController(mainViewController:nvc!, leftMenuViewController: leftViewController, rightMenuViewController: rightViewController)
    println("\(nvc!.viewControllers.count)")

    self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 236.0, green: 238.0, blue: 241.0, alpha: 1.0)
    self.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()<br>
```

and navigation from slideMenus this kind of navigation

```
func changeViewController(menu: LeftMenu) {
    switch menu {
    case .Main:
        self.slideMenuController()?.changeMainViewController(self.mainViewController, close: true)
    case .Swift:
        self.slideMenuController()?.changeMainViewController(self.swiftViewController, close: true)
        break
    case .Java:
        self.slideMenuController()?.changeMainViewController(self.javaViewController, close: true)
        break
    case .Go:
        self.slideMenuController()?.changeMainViewController(self.goViewController, close: true)
        break
    case .NonMenu:
        self.slideMenuController()?.changeMainViewController(self.nonMenuViewController, close: true)
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

in slideMenuController the function

```
public func changeMainViewController(mainViewController: UIViewController,  close: Bool) {

    removeViewController(self.mainViewController)
    self.mainViewController = mainViewController
    setUpViewController(mainContainerView, targetViewController: mainViewController)
    if (close) {
        closeLeft()
        closeRight()
    }
}
```

i am trying to remove also navigation stack of appdelegate and assign it again while changing the menu. but it didn't work.how can i achieve. please help me out.

Comment: github library link?

Comment: are you talking about this one ?? https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift

Comment: yes.its SliderMenuController from github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is in your JavaViewController , correct it like this :-

```
class JavaViewController: UIViewController {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     var btn : UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(150, 150, 60, 60))
     btn.setTitle("Click", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
     btn.addTarget(self, action: "btnClick:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
     view.addSubview(btn)


 }

 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)
     self.setNavigationBarItem()
 }

 func btnClick(sender: UIButton) {

     var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainViewController") as! MainViewController
     let leftViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftViewController") as! LeftViewController

     let nvc: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)
     leftViewController.mainViewController = nvc
     self.slideMenuController()?.changeMainViewController(nvc, close: true)

 }

}
```

Comment: User your viewcontrollers identifier name correctly and, use UINavigationControlleris if showing view controller is a navigation controller otherwise use as? viewController

Comment: it's navigate to viewcontroller but on that viewcontroller navigation is not shown.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/27qadi2q8gbab7g/AADNlVS8wcuxaHQDmwvmYmqGa?dl=0 this this the dropbox link

Comment: Please provide your CODE not  example from the github, this project works perfectly ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90843/discussion-between-chandra-vaghasiya-and-chathuranga-silva).

Comment: i made the changes into this github example for testing.like add uibutton in javaviewcontroller and navigate to mainviewcontroller. now you navigate to javaviewcontroller from the left menu it's redirect to mainviewcontroller